# Capybara loses cookies between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, capybara

I have the follow test:

```
  def login_user(email, password)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'E-mail', with: email
    fill_in 'Password', with: password
    click_button 'go'
  end

  scenario 'some test' do
    order = Fabricate(:order_one, company: user.company)
    visit "http://127.0.0.1:49645/orders/#{order.id}" # change to visit "/orders/#{order.id}"
    login_user(user.email, user.password)

    #assert
  end
```

Whats happen is that in first step (`visit...`) the user is not logged, so I set some informations using cookie. But, when `login_user` is executed, this cookie is empty.

Usigin selenium-webdriver

Any idea here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setting cookies is driver-specific. What capybara driver are you using and can you post the code for `login_user`?

Comment: Perhaps also utilize the [show-me-the-cookies gem](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies) to ensure that you really properly set the cookies in the `login_user` method.

Comment: @BoraMa update the question with more infos.

Comment: @BoraMa I debug my controller code (when I set the cookie) and it seems ok

Comment: at moment that I execute ``login_user`` the cookie was gone..

Comment: "at moment that I execute login_user the cookie was gone." - how do you know? how do you check this?

Answer (score 0):

When using a JS capable driver `#visit` is not guaranteed to have finished loading the page when it returns. Since the cookie is not set in the browser until the response is processed, your `login_user` is actually telling the browser to stop processing it's current visit and visit somewhere else which stops the cookie from ever being set in the browser.  After the first visit you need to wait for something visible on the page to be sure the cookies are correctly set.

```
scenario 'some test' do
  order = Fabricate(:order_one, company: user.company)
  visit "http://127.0.0.1:49645/orders/#{order.id}"
  expect(page).to have_content('you are not logged in') #or whatever shows on the page visited
  login_user(user.email, user.password)

  #assert
end
```

Comment: Well, expect for some content before call ``login_user`` show me the cookie using ``show_me_the_cookies``, but when I insert ``    puts "-> #{cookies["redirect_prev"]}"`` in my controller, returns empty

Comment: If show me the cookies is showing that a cookie is set in the browser and then that cookie isn't set in the controller on the next visit, that would imply the cookie isn't set correctly. Maybe you're not setting it on the correct domain - your first visit is to 127.0.0.1 -- is the second visit to that or is it to 'http://example.com' (or other) -- that would affect the domain name the cookie is bound to, and if they don't match the cookie wouldn't be sent.  If those both match, are you setting a path for the cookie that wouldn't allow it to be accessed from the other path?

Comment: You are right. The problem is that I am was using different domain. I just change it to ``visit "/orders/#{order.id}"`` and all works fine. Thanks for the help